# Fetch last occurrence of the log in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have a set of log, and i need to fetch the last occurrence of the same. Here is how the block looks like

```
Log Line 1 - Start Transaction 
Log Line 2 - Event Element1
Log Line 3 - Event Action1
Log Line 4 - Event Action2
Log Line 5 - Event Element2
Log Line 6 - Event Action3
Log Line 7 - Event Action4
Log Line 8 - Event Element3
Log Line 9 - Event Action5
Log Line 10 - Event Action6
Log Line 11 - End Transaction
```

I need to fetch the Log Line 8 - Event Element3, which is last occurance of Element Event.

I know logstash reads the logs sequentially, so there is no way to keep a counter.

Please suggest any workaround.

Comment: As you said, you can't mantain a status between different logs (they are read atomically). You could create a timestamp while loading data, then use a query with a regex like "Element*" and order your results on Kibana using the timestamp to get the last occurrence.

BTW, what you mean exactly with fetching? You want simply fetch your data for Kibana, you need to automatically get only the last field on an external system (like Spark), or what? There could be a different solutions based on your needs.

Comment: By fetching i mean I want to parse only that particular line of log which has the last occurrence. Thanks for replying.